# loading the model in the constructor function in codeigniter. is that good practice or no?

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to know...can I load the model in my constructor function instead of loading it for each function within that controller?

Lets say that I have 5 functions that use same model. Instad of calling the same model in all 5 functions, should I load the controller in the construcor function like this?

Is this good practice or no??

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class BackOfficeUsers extends MY_Controller 
{

    // constructor function 
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('backOfficeUsersModel'); // load it here??
    } // end of constructor function
```

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is always a good practice.

You can also use [CodeIgniter's Autoloading feature](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html). If you find yourself loading this model too often in other controllers.

Comment: I agree, just use the autoload.php